# ¿Que comando uso para calcular la media de la mitad de una de las columnas de mi base de datos en R?

Tags: r

¿Que comando uso para calcular la media de la mitad  de una de las columnas de mi base de datos en R?

Answer (score 0):

Si divides el problema en problemas más pequeños es más sencillo de ver por dónde va la solución:

1. ¿Cómo se calcula la media de un vector?
2. ¿Cómo seleccionamos la mitad de los valores de un vector?

Empezamos por lo último: dividir un vector en dos partes, tomemos como ejemplo el habitual `mtcars` y supongamos que queremos obtener una mitad de los valores de la variable `mpg`:

```
# La primera mitad
head(mtcars$mpg, length(mtcars$mpg)/2)
# La última mitad
tail(mtcars$mpg, length(mtcars$mpg)/2)
# La mitad pero al azar
sample(mtcars$mpg, length(mtcars$mpg)/2)
```

Finalmente, calcular la media, será simplemente aplicar `mean()` sobre el vector que contiene justamente la mitad de los valores:

```
# La primera mitad
mean(head(mtcars$mpg, length(mtcars$mpg)/2))
# La última mitad
mean(tail(mtcars$mpg, length(mtcars$mpg)/2))
# La mitad pero al azar
mean(sample(mtcars$mpg, length(mtcars$mpg)/2))
```